# ios7 - delete a tableview object in Parse backend

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

Two questions:

How to delete objects in iOS/Parse?

How to rearrange objects?

Code to delete is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
            [currentItem deleteInBackground];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}
```

nothing happens with this code. No crash but also, no change.

Rearranging - code is only:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    return YES;
}
```

This works, but does not stick - next run, the rows are back in original order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check delete process completed successfully.
check the following snippet

```
[self.currentItem deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if(!error){
                [self.tableView reloadData]; // if you are using normal table view

                // if you are using PFQueryTableViewController
                //[self.pfqueryTableViewController loadObjects];
            }
            else
            {
                // check error
            }
        }];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I logged the lines in the code, and there seems to be something funky going on. The app does now do the delete, but it deletes the wrong item.. I will mark this answer as correct, but I'm open to more suggestions.

Comment: Thanks again. You got me focused on the right area. It turned out that the currentItem did not have the correct index. Thank goodness for logging.